# Why its Choosing similar images?

Tags: javascript

i was trying to make a facemash like site using js. But when i click on an image is not changing the images rightly. its sometime showing same images in both the img elements. here the js code i use for selecting images when clicked.

```
function changeEle(id) {
    var otherSrc = id == 0? imageElements[1].src : imageElements[0].src;

    var ele = imageElements[id];
    var oldSrc = ele.src;
    var newSrc = randomFromArray(imagesList);
    while(newSrc == oldSrc || newSrc == otherSrc) {
        newSrc = randomFromArray(imagesList);
    }
    ele.src = newSrc;
}

imageElements[0].onclick = function() {
    changeEle(1);
}
imageElements[1].onclick = function() {
    changeEle(0);
}
```

Comment: You will need to place your images in different areas i.e. forehead, left cheek, right cheek, nose etc etc. Then, depending on what image is clicked then the corresponding area image will be replaced.

Comment: y should i do that.. i want to fix my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what `oldSrc` and `otherSrc` contain with a debugger or `console.log()`. I think you'll find that the values aren't exactly the same as the original values in `imagesList`, so that when you do the comparison `(newSrc == oldSrc || newSrc == otherSrc)` images that are the same image as far as you're concerned manage to slip by.

Comment: thanks it helped me. oldSrc also had the file (file://) protocal